# C - How to persist array if struct in file

Tags: c, file, fwrite

This is what i got so far but im not actually writing on the file. I think im not using correctly **fwrite()**

```
typedef struct t_directory {
  int index;
  char nombre[255];
  int padre;
}t_directory;

int main(void) {

    t_directory* tabla[100];

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<100;i++){
        tabla[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct t_directory));
        tabla[i]->index = 0;
        sprintf(tabla[i]->nombre, "");
        tabla[i]->padre = 0;
    }

    tabla[0]->index = 0;
    sprintf(tabla[0]->nombre, "root");
    tabla[0]->padre= -1;

    tabla[1]->index = 1;
    sprintf(tabla[1]->nombre, "user");
    tabla[1]->padre= 0;

    FILE * file= fopen("directorios.txt", "wb");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fwrite(tabla[0], sizeof(struct t_directory), sizeof(struct t_directory), file);
        for(i=1;i<100;i++){
            if(tabla[i]->index != 0){
                fwrite(tabla[i], sizeof(struct t_directory), sizeof(struct t_directory), file);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
```

How should i be doing it?

Comment: Don't do it in C use a more appropriate language.

Comment: `fwite(data,size_of_one_piece, count_of_pieces, file)` you use third parameter wrong

Comment: @BensaysNotoPoliticsonSO sadly i have to use C

Comment: @JacekCz Nope, already tried changing it to 1 and 3 hardcoded and i got the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the file is *binary* so you should not really be able to read it as text.

Secondly, and the source of your problem, is how you write the structure:

```
fwrite(tabla[0], sizeof(struct t_directory), sizeof(struct t_directory), file);
```

If you read e.g. [this `fwrite` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) you will see that the two size-arguments is:

1. Size of the data structure
2. The *number* of data structures

You get the second size-argument wrong, and the call attempts to write in total `sizeof(struct t_directory) * sizeof(struct t_directory)` bytes to the file, every time you call `fwrite`.

Correct should be to write *one* structure:

```
fwrite(tabla[0], sizeof(struct t_directory), 1, file);
//                                           ^
// Note the value one here, to write only a single structure
```

---

If you don't care about the space on the disk (which will be minimal for your table) then I suggest you write the whole array in one go instead.

For this to work you of course need to have an array of *objects* instead of pointers:

```
t_directory tabla[100];
```

Then you could write it all in one call:

```
fwrite(tabla, sizeof tabla[0], sizeof tabla / sizeof tabla[0], file);
```

Comment: structure MAY HAVE alignment problem, some things are not obvious

Comment: @JacekCz The compiler will most likely add padding so it shouldn't be a problem. Unless the file is copied to another platform with different alignment requirements or course.